# In Sublime Text, how can I replace a character with its Unicode?

Tags: unicode, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, how can I replace a character with its Unicode?  For example, I want to replace 中 with 4E2D (or \u4E2D or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text can be extended through Python [plugins](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/plugins/):

1. Sublime comes with functionality that generates a skeleton of Python code needed to write a simple plugin. Select *Tools* | *Developer* | *New Plugin...* in the menu.
2. Replace its content with the following code snippet:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SwapuniCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run( self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            if not region.empty():
                # Get the selected text
                s = self.view.substr(region)
                # Transform it
                x = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode()
                if x == s:
                    x = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')
                # Replace the selection with transformed text
                self.view.replace(edit, region, x)
```

3. Save to `Packages/User/swapuni.py`.

You can run it via entering `view.run_command('swapuni')` in the Sublime Text console (accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>), or by the following sublime-keymap (use your own keyboard shortcut in *Preferences* | *Key Bindings*):

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r"], "command": "swapuni" }
]
```